# Ограничение ввода в Edit

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь в следующем: нужно ограничить ввод в **Edit**, возможность вводить только положительные, отрицательные числа и числа с запятой т.е.(**1**, **-1**, **0.1**)
Заранее всем спасибо

Comment: Если **MaskEdit** http://beluch.ru/progr/100comp/3_3_3.htm не помогает, то возможно при помощи регулярок это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем обработчик OnKeyPress:

```
procedure TMainForm.EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    begin
      // разрешить ввод цифр, запятой, знака '-' и backspace
      if not (key in ['0'.. '9', #8, #45, #44]) then
        // в противном случае не вводить ничего
        key:= #0;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

У компонента `TEdit` есть событие `OnChange`, которое вызывается при изменении текста. В обработчике этого события можно проверять какой введен текст и, например, удалять символы, которые не нужны.